# Método recursivo falla

Tags: php, sql, recursión

En la aplicación que estoy realizando estoy creando un método permite cambiar el orden de las paradas por las que pasa un autobús, el orden que tienen las paradas lo tiene un campo llamado `ORDEN`.

He pensado que la mejor opción para llevar un control del orden y que no se repitan paradas con el mismo número de orden es crear un método recursivo a partir del antiguo método que no hice yo.

El método es el siguiente y consiste en que, cuando le envío la parada, la actualiza a la nueva posición, después comprueba si hay paradas distintas en esa posición, si las hay, recojo sus datos y vuelvo a llamar al método con esa parada y con su posición +1:

```
function cambiarOrdenRecorrido() {              
    try {
        $db = getDbCon();
        $RECORRIDO=$_POST['recorrido'];
        $ANIO=$_POST['anio'];
        $TRPANUM=$_POST['ordenParada'];
        $POSICION = $_POST["posicion"];
        $TRECCOD = $_POST["codrecorrido"];

        if(!is_numeric($POSICION) || $POSICION < 0){
            echo json_encode(Array('ok' => FAILED, 'msg' => $lang['ERROR_POSICION']));
            return;
        }

        $RECORRIDOANIO = $RECORRIDO . $ANIO;

        //PRIMERO GUARDO EL CAMBIO EN LA PARADA SELECIONADA
        $strSQL =  'UPDATE PARADASRECORRIDOS SET TRPANUM = ?,TRECCOD = ? WHERE CONCAT(TSRVJOR, LPAD(TSRVHOR, 4, 0), TSRVDIR, TRECCOD, TSRVANO) = ? AND PARCOD = ?';
        $stmt = $db->prepare($strSQL);
        $stmt->bind_param('iisi', $POSICION,$TRECCOD,$RECORRIDOANIO, $PARCOD);
        $stmt->execute();
        //DESPUES COMPRUEBO SI HAY MAS RECORRIDOS EN ESA POSICION
        $strSQL =  'SELECT PARCOD,TRECCOD,TSRVANO,CONCAT(TSRVJOR, LPAD(TSRVHOR, 4, 0), TSRVDIR, TRECCOD, TSRVANO) AS RECORRIDO FROM PARADASRECORRIDOS WHERE TRPANUM = ? and CONCAT(TSRVJOR, LPAD(TSRVHOR, 4, 0), TSRVDIR, TRECCOD, TSRVANO) = ? and PARCOD <> ?';
        $stmt = $db->prepare($strSQL);
        $stmt->bind_param('isi', $POSICION,$RECORRIDOANIO,$PARCOD);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($PARCOD,$TRECCOD,$TSRVANO,$RECORRIDO);
        $resultado = array();
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            $tmp = array();                     
            $tmp["PARCOD"] = $PARCOD;               
            $tmp["TRECCOD"] = $TRECCOD;             
            $tmp["TSRVANO"] = $TSRVANO;             
            $tmp["RECORRIDO"] = $RECORRIDO;                                             
            array_push($resultado, $tmp);
        }
        if(count($resultado)!= 0){
            $_POST["recorrido"]=$resultado[0]["TSRVANO"];
            $_POST['anio']=$resultado[0]["TSRVANO"];
            $_POST['codParada']=$resultado[0]["PARCOD"];
            $_POST['ordenParada'] = -1;
            $_POST["posicion"] = $POSICION + 1;
            $_POST["codrecorrido"] = $resultado[0]["TRECCOD"];
            cambiarOrdenRecorrido();    
            echo "HAY IGUALES";
        }else{
            $result = true;
        }   
        $db->close();

         // Check for successful insertion          
        if ($result) {
            // CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
            echo json_encode(Array('ok' => SUCCESSFULL));
            return;

        } else {
            //return FAILED;
            echo json_encode(Array('ok' => FAILED, 'msg' => $stmt->error));
            return;
        }              
    } catch (Exception $e) {            

        $log->logError("recorrido.php -> setJSONParadaRecorrido ->" . $e->getMessage());
        echo json_encode(Array('ok' => FAILED, 'msg' => $e->getMessage()));
        return;
    }
}
```

El error que me devuelve es el siguiente:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 11
> {"ok":true}{"ok":true}

Este ocurre solo cuando cambio el orden y este orden ya está ocupado. Esto es porque pasa dos veces por:

```
if ($result) {
    // CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY;
    echo json_encode(Array('ok' => SUCCESSFULL));
    return;             
} else {
    //return FAILED;
    echo json_encode(Array('ok' => FAILED, 'msg' => $stmt->error));
    return;
}
```

Comment: No me parece buena practica modificar las variables de sistema $_POST para el uso que le estas dando. Lo mas correcto seria que llamaras con otras variables, sino vas a perder la peticion post...

Answer (score 1):

Como tú mismo indicas, el problema es que estás generando un JSON inválido. Mejor dicho, estás generando **partes** válidas de un JSON, que son enviadas de forma independiente. Al recibirlas **e intentar unirlas**, es cuando se produce el error.

Una posible solución:

- Antes de llamar por primera vez a `cambiarOrdenRecorrido( )`:

`echo '[';`

- En todos tus `json_encode( ... )`:

`echo json_encode( ... ), ',';`

- Después de terminar con `cambiarOrdenRecorrido( )`:

`echo ']';`

De ese modo, generas un JSON que es **una lista** de objetos. No sé si te valdrá así, o tienes requerimientos especiales con el valor de retorno.

Comment: El problema es que la llamada la hago por Ajax, como podría ejecutar un echo antes y despues de la llamada con Ajax?

Comment: En el código PHP que usas, en algún momento, se realizará la llamada a `cambiarOrdenRecorrido( )`. Pués ahí, en PHP, es donde has de colocar el `echo`.

Comment: Estoy probando y el problema que veo que cuando acaba la ejecucion el json queda asi `[{"ok":true},]{"ok":true},]` con una coma al final. supongo que no me costara mucho cambiarlo

Comment: La coma **no debería** de importar. Creo que el estándar la permite. No debería darte error al *parsearlo*.

Comment: Pues no se porque esta fallando de todas formas me han cambiado la tarea y se la han pasado a un compañero. Asi que no puedo verificar si lo que me dices es correcto o noç

Comment: Ok. Ha pasado a ser *problema de otro* XD

Comment: El json ultimo que escribes (**[{"ok":true},]{"ok":true},]**) es erroneo. No solo por la coma (json no admite una coma final sin elemento) sino porque tienes un corchete cerrado entre medias. lo correcto seria: **[{"ok":true},{"ok":true}]**. Diselo a tu compañero. Eso de que te quiten los problemas asi mola, ya me gustaria a mi... :)

Comment: @Jakala Ese corchete no debería de estar ahí. Indico que ponga `[` **antes** de llamar a su función, y `]` **cuando termine la última llamada recursiva**. No se como aparece ese `]` O_o